# How to calculate $a_k$ with Conjugate gradients method?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I have got function like:

$3(x_1-1)^2+2(x_2-2)^2+(x_3-3)^3$
and starting point is $(9; -7; 11)$

I'm using the following algorithm:

1. $p_0 = -f'(x)$
2. $a_k = - (f'(x_k), p_k) / (p_k, H*p_k)$ and calculate $x_{k+1} = x_k + a_k*p_k$
3. if $f'(x_{k+1}) = 0$ or (less epsilon) I found my minimum, otherwise counting new $p$ and repeat step 1:
   $p_k+1 = -f'(x_{k+1}) + (f'(x_{k+1}), f'(x_{k+1})) / ((f'(x_k), f'(x_k))) * p_k$;

And I can't understand how to calculate $a_k$. I'm using it like:

$a_k = - (f'(x_k) * p_k) / p_k^2$

And it gave me unreal meanings. So how should I calculate this?

Comment: What are $F, H$?

Comment: What are unreal meanings? You may want to take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109983/beta-k-for-conjugate-gradient-method) and my answer to it. Does that clarify some things?

Comment: This looks neither like Fletcher-Reeves nor Polak-Ribiere. Where did  you get this thing you've shown us?

Comment: @J.M. From http://knigechka.blogspot.com/2010/04/blog-post_7372.html It is in russian.

Comment: @copper.hat F is a function, and I really don't know what H is it. It explained in my source as $(p_k, H*p_{k-1}) = 0$ and nothing else.

Comment: @J.M. Your question didn't help me, because it's for matrix. I just can't figure out how to implement it on equation.

Comment: No, the CG variants I mentioned are precisely the ones used for optimization. Look it up yourself if you don't want to take my word for it. (Also, a textbook has better chances of displaying the proper code as opposed to a website from some random pocket of the web.)

Comment: @J.M. Here is it http://people.equars.com/marco/poli/phd/node54.html , but still how should I calculate lambda?

Comment: My research advisor was Polak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function can be written as:
$$f(x)=(x-x^*)^T H(x-x^*)$$
where:
\begin{align}
H&=\begin{pmatrix}
3&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}& 
x^*&=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Note that it is quite obvious from the function that the minimum is achieved for $x=x*$, where the value of the function is 0.

Also, the $H$ you have in your formulas is precisely the one I have written above. The algorithm you have found is the conjugate gradient algorithm applied to a quadratic function for which we know the Hessian matrix $H$.

The gradient $f'(x)$ thus reads $f'(x)=H(x-x^*)$. I rewrite your algorithm hereunder:

1. Let $k=0$ and $p_0 = -f'(x_0)=-H(x_0-x^*)$
2. At iteration $k$, let:
   \begin{align}
   a_k &= - \frac{f'(x_k)^T p_k}{p_k^T Hp_k}\\ x_{k+1} &= x_k + a_k p_k
   \end{align}
   if $f'(x_{k+1}) = H(x_k-x^*)=0$ or ($<\varepsilon$) I found my minimum, otherwise let:
   \begin{align}
   b_k&=\frac{f'(x_{k+1})^T f'(x_{k+1})}{f'(x_k)^T f'(x_k)}\\
   p_{k+1} &= -f'(x_{k+1}) + b_k p_k
   \end{align}
   and repeat step 2.

I implemented the algorithm starting from $x_0=\begin{pmatrix} 9\\-7\\11 \end{pmatrix}$ and the iterates it produces are:
\begin{align}
x_0&=\begin{pmatrix}   9\\-7\\11 \end{pmatrix}&
x_1&=\begin{pmatrix}   -0.482\\0.1115\\7.8393 \end{pmatrix}&
x_2&=\begin{pmatrix}   1.2069\\2.8276\\4.8621 \end{pmatrix}&
x_3&=\begin{pmatrix}   1\\2\\3 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: How so?  Isn't the objective cubic??

Answer (score 0):

If you do have cube power in the last term $(x_3-3)^3$ then you don't have finite solution since when $x_3$ tends to $-\infty$ the function tends to $-\infty$ either. However in general H indeed is a Hessian matrix of your nonlinear function which is constant for the quadratic form but should be updated for a general nonlinear function on each step.